# Calculate the flux through a surface S from a field described by vectors

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I have encountered yet another example which is not that typical.

I need to calculate:
$$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \vec{ds} =\text{ ?}$$
Where the $F$ and $S$ are as follows ($S$ is oriented outwards):
$$\vec{F}=r^2 \cdot \vec{r}$$
$$S: x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$
My questions:

1. How should I interpret:
   $$r^2 \cdot \vec{r}$$
   Should it be?
   $$(x^2,y^2,z^2) \cdot (x,y,z) = (x^3,y^3,z^3)$$
2. Do I need to calculate a vector normal to the surface and substitute it in the integral? 
   I assume if needed it should look like this: 
   $$\vec{n}= \frac{\vec{r}}{R}$$
3. Can I use divergence (Gauss) theorem in that example? Or maybe I should rather stick to following formula for flux calculation through a surface?:

   ### $$\iint R-PF_x-QF_y$$

**EDIT**, based on the answer from @michaelrccurtis, below I present my solution of the example. Could you check whether it's correct?

I began with rejecting the use of 
$$\vec{n}= \frac{\vec{r}}{R}$$
since I have not seen it applied in any other example exploiting Divergence theorem. Am I right with this?

Then I determined my new set of coordinates and their range:
$$V: \left\{ (r, \varphi, \theta) \quad 0 \le r \le R; 0 \le \varphi \le 2\pi;  \frac{-\pi}{2}  \le \theta \le  \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$$
Then, I calculated the divergence of $\vec{F}$ and substituted the result into the triple integral over the volume described by $S$:

$$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \vec{ds} = \iiint\limits_{V} div\vec{F}\vec{ds}=\iiint\limits_{V} 3x^{2}+3y^{2}+3z^{2} dxdydz = \int_{0}^{R} \left[  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[  \int_{ \frac{-\pi}{2} }^{ \frac{\pi}{2} } 3R^{2} \cdot R^{2}cos \theta d \theta \right] d \varphi \right] dr =$$

$$=\int_{0}^{R} \left[  \int_{0}^{2\pi} 6R^{4} d \varphi \right] dr =\int_{0}^{R}   12 \pi R^{4}  dr=12 \pi R^{5}$$

1. Is it the right answer?
2. Is the normal vector not necessary here?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't read $\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}$ (a dot-product of vectors) and mis-copy it as $\vec{F}\,\vec{ds}$?  And should it not just be a single integral along the boundary, i.e. $\displaystyle\int\limits_{\partial S}$ rather than $\displaystyle\iint\limits_S$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, you are right with the first, that it should be $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{ds}$. But regarding the second point - it should have a symbol of $\unicode{x222F}$ but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: 2. No. You need to look carefully at the definition of the divergence theorem - note that the integral is $\iiint\limits_{V}dV$, where $dV$ is a scalar. We are changing from an integral of the flux over a surface to integrating the divergence (which is a scalar) throughout the volume contained by the surface.

Comment: 1. Not quite. You haven't quite calculated the divergence correctly, it should be $5r^2$, I think, otherwise your method looks correct. You should be careful to note the difference between $r$ and $R$ in this question.

Comment: @michaelrccurtis Thank you for answering. I just want to clarify if "2. No" means "No, this normal vector is not supposed to be used here". And regarding the 1. - I still can't figure out how did you get that $div\vec{F}$ is $5r^{2}$ from $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) (x,y,z)$ which for me is equal to $x^3+y^3+z^3$?

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a new question, as this is getting rather crowded! I'll answer when you do. Make sure you include your reasoning so we can see where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given the notation, I would assume that $$r^{2} \cdot \vec{r}$$ means:

   $$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) (x,y,z)$$
2. Yes, since
   $$\vec{dS} = \vec{\hat{n}}dS$$
   where $dS$ is the surface element and $\vec{\hat{n}}$ is the unit normal of the surface, which assuming $R\equiv|\vec{r}|$ you have correct.
3. The divergence theorem is in principle useful in problems like this, provided that the divergence exists and assuming that it gives you a form that is easier to integrate. In this case, why don't you try calculating the divergence? It has a fairly simple form.

Comment: Thank you. Why does it take the form of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and not $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ - I mean why do you add the vector components together? Ad. 3 I would have calculated it, but I wanted to make sure the $\vec{F}$ is correct.

Comment: Because $r^2$ here is clearly a scalar, and the usual convention is that $r \equiv |\vec{r}|$, which you have called $R$.

Comment: Here, the dot between $r^2$ and $\vec{r}$ just indicates normal multiplication.

Comment: Please check my EDIT, I have added a solution and I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: @PeterKowalski I have commented above.

Comment: I have created a new topic as you advised. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421867/calculate-the-flux-through-a-surface-s-and-my-approach-using-divergence-theorem