# Calculate the flux through a surface S and my approach using Divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

Since my previous, introductory question [Calculate the flux through a surface S from a field described by vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419587/calculate-the-flux-through-a-surface-s-from-a-field-described-by-vectors) about this example raised even more questions that I had initially - I was advised to post a new question and below I present my solution of the example, just to make sure if I did that correctly.

The given data:
The $F$ and $S$ are as follows ($S$ is oriented outwards):
$$\vec{F}=r^2 \cdot \vec{r}$$
$$S: x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$$
$$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \vec{ds} =\text{ ?}$$

I began with rejecting the use of vector normal to the surface:
$$\vec{n}= \frac{\vec{r}}{R}$$
since I have not seen it applied in any other example exploiting Divergence theorem.

Am I right with this?

**My solution:** (applying advice from @
$$\vec{F}=r^2 \cdot \vec{r}=  (r^2x, r^2y, r^2z)$$
$$div\vec{F}=5r^2$$
Then I determined my new set of coordinates and their range:
$$V: \left\{ (r, \varphi, \theta) \quad 0 \le r \le R; 0 \le \varphi \le 2\pi;  \frac{-\pi}{2}  \le \theta \le  \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$$
Then, I calculated the divergence of $\vec{F}$ and substituted the result into the triple integral over the volume described by $S$:

$$\iint\limits_{S} \vec{F} \vec{ds} = \iiint\limits_{V} div\vec{F}\vec{ds}=\iiint\limits_{V} 5r^2 dxdydz = \int_{0}^{R} \left[  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left[  \int_{ \frac{-\pi}{2} }^{ \frac{\pi}{2} } 5r^2 \cdot R^{2}cos \theta d \theta \right] d \varphi \right] dr =$$

$$=\int_{0}^{R} \left[  \int_{0}^{2\pi} 10r^2 \ R^2 d \varphi \right] dr =20 \pi R^2\int_{0}^{R}   r^2  dr=\frac{20}{3} \pi R^{5}$$

1. Is it the right answer?
2. Is the normal vector not supposed to be used here?

Comment: Your definition of F doesn't make any sense. It is a vector quantity yet you define it in terms of a scaler product of two things.

Comment: @JakeLebovic How should it look like then?

Comment: As per the last thread, I believe it is just the scalar multiplied by the vector, i.e. $r^2\vec{r}$.

Comment: One final point, the volume element given your limits is $r^2\mathrm{cos}(\theta)$ rather than $R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intepretation of $\vec{F}$ is wrong. You need to multiply the scalar by each component of the vector.

$$ \vec{F} = (r^2x, r^2y, r^2z)$$

Remember that the divergence is defined for a vector field - you can't apply it to a scalar. You can think of it as taking:

$$ \nabla\vec{F} = (\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y, \partial/\partial z) \cdot (r^2x, r^2y, r^2z) $$

In this case, each term is similar:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(r^2x) = \frac{\partial (r^2)}{\partial x}x + r^2 $$

where

$$\frac{\partial (r^2)}{\partial x} = 2x $$

Putting this together, we get:

$$ \nabla\vec{F} = 3r^2 + 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = 5r^2 $$

Comment: So, should the $\vec{F}$ be equal to $(x^3+y^2x+z^2x)+(x^2y+y^3+z^2y)+(x^2z+y^2z+z^3)$?

Comment: $\vec{F}$ is a vector.

Comment: Can you please show me what should I put under $div$ operator. I am trying and still do not know how to proceed. I can't figure out how did you get that $div \vec{F}$ is $5r^2$

Comment: Do you understand what the divergence is?

Comment: Apparently no. Can you describe in detail how did you get from $\vec{F} = (r^2x, r^2y, r^2z)$ to $5r^2$. For me it looks like te result should be $6r^2$, since the derivative of $r^2x, r^2y, r^2z$ versus $dx, dy, dz$ respectively is $3 \cdot r^2=6r^2$. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you. I modified my solution, you can quickly skim through and check if now it is correct. One question though - this equation $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(r^2x) = \frac{\partial (r^2)}{\partial x}x + r^2 $$ consists of two parts summed together, because it is the derivative of a multiplication. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is the product rule.